# .table data is not loading in Allure report tab in Azure devops

Tags: selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, allure, python-behave

I am using an automation testing framework with python selenium and behave. This test is integrated in azure devops. I have installed both Allure Report viewer and Allure Test Reports extension in azure devops.
Now my tests are running successfully in azure devops and allure report is also getting generated. But only the .table data is missing whenever there is an attachment

I tried to even open the attachment in a new tab but then its showing data_attachments_38d1....csv is not available on site.
However if i download allure-report from published artifact section and opening allure report using allure generate command, all the data including table is generated. This shows that all required data is available in allure-report folder and somehow the "Allure Report" tab in Azure pipeline is not able to read this.

I have tried all possible solutions and its not working

Comment: Can  you share some screenshots about the error page? And can you share the file structure of the attachment?